# Scrolling to DOM Element in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using react 16.4 and i need to scroll to a DOM element in the application. Because `refs` are now deprecated in react I am searching for the cleanest way to achive this.

But from my point of view it's hard to find a solution without `ref` and also without manipulating the DOM directly like this:

```
document.getElementById("questions").lastElementChild.scrollIntoView({
  behavior: "smooth"
});
```

What is currently the best way to do stuff like this?

best regards

Comment: refs are not deprecated, they just changed their api. https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can still use `React.createRef()`. Only string refs and callbacks are deprecated/in the process of being deprecated.

```
import React, {Component, createRef} from 'react'
class App extends Component {    
  myRef = createRef()   // Create a ref object     
  scrollToRef = () => 
    window.scrollTo(0, this.myRef.current.offsetTop); 

  render() {
    return <div ref={this.myRef}></div> 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[`React.createRef`](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) was introduced in `16.3`, so you could use that. Put it on an element and use the `scrollIntoView` method on the `current` property, which is the DOM node.

**Example**

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  bottomRef = React.createRef();

  onClick = () => {
    this.bottomRef.current.scrollIntoView();
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.onClick}>Scroll to bottom</button>
        <div style={{ height: 2000 }} />
        <div ref={this.bottomRef}>bottom</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to Component for animating vertical scrolling https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-scroll